# IIS 8 returning 403 instead of 404?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis-8

When I test locally and I try and browse to a non-existent page I correctly trigger my custom 404 page.
However when I deploy to IIS and I try and browse to a non-existent page it returns a 403.
I tried to fix it by adding in a path for the status code but it didn't catch it.

Here's my httpErrors section:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
    <remove statusCode="404" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/Http404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    <remove statusCode="403"/>
    <error statusCode="403" path="/Error/Http404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    <remove statusCode="500" />
    <error statusCode="500" path="/Error/Http500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue but only if the site is deployed as sub-application under Default Web Site so it has virtual path. If it is a separate IIS site everything works as expected.